# Member Group Information Angular2 Azure AD

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using [ng2-adal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-adal) to integrate my Angular app with Azure AD login. My application should only be accessible to certain groups within my organization. Currently when I query the adal-service for user-info the jwt doesn't contain any groups information.

I figure I would query Microsoft Graph API to get `/me/memberOf` info but I get `Access denied` to this information and require an Admin to grant me permissions to view this data.

Is there any other way of getting this information or do I have to bug my IT dept to enable `READ` permissions for groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid so, anything that looks at Groups requires Admin Consent.

It certainly seems reasonable that you should be able to see your own membership (`/me/memberOf`) with `User.Read`. That said, I'm far from an information security expert there may good reasons for not allowing it.

Regardless, I would highly recommend adding this suggestion to the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis). They do have